# For loop explanation what does for(;;) mean

Tags: php, for-loop, syntax, conditional-statements

I have looked at some open source code and came across this...

```
for(;;) {
   echo "a:" . $throttle->throttle($identifier, 5, 1000);
}
```

What does the ;; stand for within the for statement - i've never come across that before?

Comment: It's simply creating an infinite loop, no conditions for initializing, terminating or adjusting during for the iterations.... personally I'd prefer `while(true)`, as it's more intuitive what it means

Comment: great - i got it working and realised the same :) feel free to add that as an answer for me to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as while(true), an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is an infinite loop. In a typical for loop there are expressions between the semicolons. If you leave it blank it's meant to be a loop that never ends.

Answer (score 1):

It's an infinite loop.
Anatomy of a for loop is

```
  for (initialization_expression ; test_condition; update_expression) 
  {
        // Code 
  }
```

In your case all 3 parts are missing. Since test condition is missing , it will evaluate as true and loop will continue for ever.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is explained at *Language Reference → Control Structures → [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)* (emphasis mine):

> ```
> for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> **Each of the expressions can be empty** or contain multiple expressions separated by commas. In expr2, all expressions separated
>   by a comma are evaluated but the result is taken from the last part.
>   **expr2 being empty means the loop should be run indefinitely** (PHP implicitly considers it as TRUE, like C). This may not be as useless
>   as you might think, since often you'd want to end the loop using a
>   conditional break statement instead of using the for truth expression.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `for(initialization;condition;increment/decrement)`
so the *initialization* is called once, before the for loop starts.
The *last two parameters* are evaluated after every iteration.

Now if you remove the terminating condition, it is equivalent to a `while(true)` loop.
Other parameters are also ignored, as in your question, as they are also optional and not needed in your case.